# from plone.app.content.batching import Batch fails with ImportError: No module named batching

Tags: plone

I just upgraded to Plone 4.3 and I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named batching
```

Answer (score 2):

plone.app.content no more provides a batching implementation.

Replace

```
from plone.app.content.batching import Batch
```

with

```
try:
    from plone.app.content.batching import Batch # Plone < 4.3
    HAS_PLONE43 = False
except ImportError:
    from plone.batching import Batch # Plone >= 4.3
    HAS_PLONE43 = True
```

[**EDIT**]

The two implementations have a different API: the `pagesize` argument is named `size` in plone.app.batching; also, instead of a page number a start index is required.

If you have code that looks like this

```
    b = Batch(items,
            pagesize=pagesize,
            pagenumber=pagenumber)
```

replace it with

```
    if HAS_PLONE43:
        b = Batch(items,
                size=pagesize,
                start=pagenumber * pagesize)
    else:
        b = Batch(items,
                pagesize=pagesize,
                pagenumber=pagenumber)
```

Comment: Correct. The move happened in December 2011. Look at the github repo's commit log to confirm :-)

Comment: @izak: I wasn't sure the implementations are interchangeable. Besides, two sets of eyes are better than one. Thanks! I removed the warning.